# Bundler ignores "no_proxy"

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I finally got a gem server to work in our lan that serves the gems we have created for our project. But those gems have some dependencies to each other and 3rd party gems.

And while our "private" gems reside on the local gem server, the 3rd party gems reside on sites like rubygems.org, etc

Since our lan is behind a proxy I have to set the $http_proxy $https_proxy variables to get to the internet. And for stuff that should not be resolved via proxy I set the $no_proxy variable.

Unfortunately bundler/ruby doesn't seem care for the $no_proxy variable?

In my gemfile I have set all URLs needed. The internal and the external ones. But when the proxy (including $no_proxy with the local URL) is set I get a gateway timeout from the proxy for the local gem server.

Is there a way (without patching the Bundler/Ruby sources) to tell Bundler/Ruby to obey proxy excludes?

Cheers,
Stefan

Answer (score 1):

Strangely enough I hit the same problem today.

As a workaround I ended up installing [CNTLM](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/). It points to my upstream proxy but is configured (via NoProxy option in cntlm.conf) to ignore it for certain hosts.

I also had to set the `$http_proxy` environment variable to point at CNTLM (http://localhost:3128 by default) rather than my upstream proxy.

Comment: Might be a way to go. Only problem is that you then have two proxies.

Comment: +1 for the idea, I'd rather use something like proxychains though

Answer (score 1):

I dug a little deeper and found out that Ruby's `Net::HTTPSession` just plain doesn't contain any code for excluding hosts from a proxy lookup. Since Bundler uses this class there's no way it obeys the `no_proxy` variable.

**My workaround:**

I ended up collecting all the gems we need for our Ruby projects and put them on our local gem server. That's definitely not ideal. But at least it gives me some more control over the Gems used in our projects.

As I read in the Ruby bug tracker, a `no_proxy` awareness will be included in Ruby 2.0. This means we have to live with workarounds for now.